# Determine whether all zero for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation:
y''(x) + p(x)y'(x) - y(x) = 0, where y(a) and y(b) is zero, p(x) is a smooth real-valued function.

I have proven that the the interval [a,b] is identically zero by using local max. and local min. argument. However, is y(x) identically zero for all x? My first guess is no by imagining the function is [a,b] zero and outside is an ever increasing or decreasing function to make sure no local max./min. (i.e. y'(x) not equal to 0). I tried to to figure out some counter examples by assuming y(x) is a piecewise function with simple polynomial outside.

But when I tried to solve the guessed setup, it always leads to wrong answer (e.g. after solving some algebra, then leads to a constant equal to zero for a few guessed p(x) and y(x)).

I started thinking my assumption is wrong but I have no idea how to prove y(x) identically zero for all x. Can someone give me some hints on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider an initial value problem starting at $b$ using $y(b)=0$ (given) and $y'(b)=0$ (follows from the solution being identically zero on $[a,b]$). One solution to that is clearly $y=0$. Since you have uniqueness, it is the only one. You can do the analogous thing for $x<a$.

Comment: I think get the point. But can I do like this: Suppose c is a point within [a,b], y(c) and y'(c) are both zero. One solution is simply y(x)=0 and this solution  matches the two initial condition. Therefore, by the uniqueness of the solution I can know the whole function is just y(x)=0? (Just want to check if I get things right)

Comment: @tomchan516 Sure, that works too. There was nothing special about $b$, you just need a point where you can start an IVP with both initial conditions being zero. In fact you don't have to continue separately starting at $a$ either, the solution continues backward in time from $b$.